# How can I read values of a pointer, being this pointer the return of a function?

Tags: c++

This would be my code:

```
uint8_t* send(uint16_t sw){

uint8_t sw8[2];
uint8_t* data= NULL;

sw8[0]=sw>>8;
sw8[1]=sw&0xFF;

memcpy(data,sw,2);

return data;

}

main(){
uint8_t * resp;

resp = send(x6A00);
}
```

If sw is 0x6A00 for example, *data will be 6A, and I want it to be 6A00!!!!

Comment: Either allocate the array dynamically, or make it static.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do - do you want a pointer to a byte buffer with the `sw` value in it?

Comment: `memcpy()` only copies. It does not allocate. You can't write to (or dereference, or etc.) a null pointer. `main()` returns `int`. Please also try to better state the problem when posting.

Comment: Search the internet for "Big Endian" and "Little Endian".

Answer (score 1):

```
uint8_t* data= NULL;
...
memcpy(data,sw,2);
```

Here, you pass null to `memcpy`. The behaviour of the program is undefined.

> I want [`*data`] to be 6A00!!!!

Then `data` must point to some array. You can achieve this by initialising the pointer. Exactly how you should do that depends on what you're trying to do.

> I want data to point to the sw8. But if I put data=sw8, i will get &sw8[0], i don't access to the whole array, right?

Sure you do. You can simply use `data[1]` to access the second element.

However, if you do this, then you shouldn't return `data` because `sw8` is an automatic variable within the function, and therefore its lifetime ends and it is automatically destroyed by the end of the function. Therefore returning a pointer to it always returns an invalid pointer.

Comment: I want data to point to the sw8. But if I put data=sw8, i will get &sw8[0], i don't access to the whole array, right?